# How to remove n number of lines from a file using sed command?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

I want to remove a particular number of lines after the given pattern is matched.

Can anyone please tell me how that can be done using the `sed` command ?

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -ne '/pattern/{n;n;n;n;d;}' -e p
```

Would delete the line matching the *pattern* and 4 lines after that.

If you don't want to delete the line matching the pattern itself:

```
sed -ne '/pattern/{p;n;n;n;n;d;}' -e p
```

Explanation: if the current line matches the *pattern*, [p]rint it, then get the [n]ext one, and [n]ext and [n]ext, and [n]ext and [d]iscard it. Because of the [d]iscard, the [p]rint command is not run in that case. It is run for every other line. `-n` disables automatic printing (which would print almost everything) and thus implies the use of `-e p`, which  makes sure the resulting lines are printed.

Example:

```
$ seq 8 | sed -ne '/2/{p;n;n;n;n;d;}' -e p
1
2
7
8
```

To be able to specify the number of lines as a number, it would be easier with `awk`:

```
awk 'n>0 {n--;next}; /pattern/{n=4}; 1'
```

(note that in all those solutions, the pattern is not looked for in the lines that are being skipped).

Comment: yes I would like to delete the lines after the pattern matching . Can you provide easy understanding of sed command tutorial ?

Comment: Could you please explain the terms used in 'sed -ne '/pattern/{p;n;n;n;n;d;}' -e p' comamnd

Answer (score 0):

Two step, assuming bash. Assuming 2 lines to be removed *after* the lines containing "pattern".
Note: The line which contains pattern is NOT removed, but 2 lines after that are removed.

To remove `N` lines, change `A2` -> `AN` in grep arguments

```
grep -n -A2 pattern inputFile | grep -Ev pattern | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)-.*/\1/g' > linesToRemove

while read p; do sed -i "${p}d" inputFile; done < linesToRemove
```

If you also want to delete the line containing pattern, change grep command to

```
grep -n -A2 pattern inputFile | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)[-:].*/\1/g' > linesToRemove
```

Explanation: First command finds out line numbers of lines to be deleted. Second command deletes these lines one after another. Use http://explainshell.com/ to learn more or just `man grep`

If your sed does not have `-i` option, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400287/1729501